# Memory leak due to updating a large number of files (gulp, watch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, frontend

Project structure looks like this

```
app
=global //include for all pages
====component_1
====component_2
==pages 
====page_1
======page_1.css
======page_1.jade
======page_1.js
dist (place for build)
==page_1    
====global
======main.js
====page_1.js
====page_1.css
====index.html
```

There is a task that monitors page changes.

example for *.js

```
const JSPageWatcher= gulp.watch('app/pages/**/*.js') //такая же на CSS и Jade
  JSPageWatcher.on('change', e => {
    console.log('File ' + e + ' was, running tasks...')
    slideJS(e.split('\\').pop().replace('.js', '')) 
  })
```

And for components

```
 gulp.watch('app/components/*.js', gulp.series('webpack'))
```

it is enough to open the component file in the IDE and the watcher will start updating all pages, and the watchers will start to work after each type of page file because messages for many pages will sprinkle to the console

```
app\pages\4_44\4_44.css
File app\pages\4_44\4_44.css, running tasks...
File app\pages\4_45_D\4_45_D.js was, running tasks...
app\pages\4_45\4_45.css
File app\pages\4_45\4_45.css, running tasks...
app\pages\4_48\4_48.css
File app\pages\4_48\4_48.css, running tasks...
app\pages\4_46\4_46.css
File app\pages\4_46\4_46.css, running tasks...
```

Apparently all this is cached and eventually crashes with an error like:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1644:000001A56BBA23F0]  6744991 ms: Mark-sweep 1371.8 (1425.1) -> 1371.4 (1425.1) MB, 1043.3 / 3.2 ms  (average mu = 0.150, current mu = 0.018) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
[1644:000001A56BBA23F0]  6746176 ms: Mark-sweep 1372.1 (1425.1) -> 1371.7 (1425.1) MB, 1172.5 / 6.4 ms  (average mu = 0.083, current mu = 0.011) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 000001BDFE750361]
Security context: 0x03cfae81d9f1 <JSObject>
    1: /* anonymous */ [000003B954E99759] [D:\project\MyProjects\MyProject\node_modules\readdirp\stream-api.js:~37] [pc=000001BE00E89890](this=0x03b954e99569 <ReaddirpReadable map = 00000200F40F1511>)
    2: emit [000003CFAE845E51] [events.js:~140] [pc=000001BE00C23535](this=0x03b954e99569 <ReaddirpReadable map = 00000200F40F1511>,0x03b1a529c6d...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF61B8AABAA v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+4810
 2: 00007FF61B850C96 uv_loop_fork+80486
 3: 00007FF61B851BC0 uv_loop_fork+84368
 4: 00007FF61BCCDC6E v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+798
 5: 00007FF61BCCDBA7 v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+599
 6: 00007FF61BFA6E24 v8::internal::Heap::RootIsImmortalImmovable+14788
 7: 00007FF61BF9CA64 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+7556
 8: 00007FF61BF9B138 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage+1112
 9: 00007FF61BFA4AA7 v8::internal::Heap::RootIsImmortalImmovable+5703
10: 00007FF61BFA4B26 v8::internal::Heap::RootIsImmortalImmovable+5830
11: 00007FF61BB65611 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+49
12: 00007FF61C2C03DA v8::internal::StoreBuffer::StoreBufferOverflow+26826
13: 000001BDFE750361
```

where the main line is a memory leak.

Question: What can cause this behavior? Where to look to solve the problem of the start of the watchers on all files, although they did not change anything and did not save the file?

```
gulp version: 4.0
node version: 8.11 and 11.2
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?